# Scala way of if else with two conditional variables

Tags: scala, if-statement, coding-style, modularity

I have a the following Java snippet (where `a` and `b` are futures):

```scala
if (a.isEmpty && b.isEmpty) func(list)
else if (a.isEmpty) func(list, b)
else if (b.isEmpty) func(a, list)
else func(a, list, b)
```

I have all the implementations of the function 'func'.
Is there a proper way to write this in Scala or is this good enough?

Comment: I am extending an existing class which already have the implementations.

Comment: What are `a`, `b`, `list`, and `func`?

Comment: Under the assumption that a and b are not equal to the type of list it's typesafe and conform for overloading.

Comment: It's type safe even if they are all the same type. There are three overloads, taking one, two and three arguments of the same type.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `a` and `b` are lists, which seems likely as they seem related to `list`:

```
(a, b) match {
  case (Nil, Nil) => func(list)
  case (Nil, _)   => func(list, b)
  case (_, Nil)   => func(a, list)
  case _          => func(a, b, list)
}
```

Comment: actually they are Futures

Comment: Ok. Kind of useful for you to have everything said that earlier!

Comment: I'm not sure about the meaning of `isEmpty` if `a` and `b` are Futures.

Comment: Are you sure they're not lists of Futures? `Future` doesn't have an `isEmpty` method